# sf::Font::loadFromFile crashing the program

Tags: c++, windows, crash, sfml

I've been testing some Features in SFML 2.3 Recently, and I have started to get comfortable with C++.
After playing around, I decided to try adding Text into programs, with `sf::Text`, and `sf::Font`.

Upon doing so, I've been getting issues when running the program, even using the tutorial for it.

I have tried debugging it, but haven't seen any issues from that, but when running, about the point where it draws 'text', a dialog box comes up saying "text.exe has stopped working"

I'm running Windows 10 10586, and I'm using VS2012 Professional.

I have code below, of what I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800,600),"Text Test");
    sf::Text text;
    sf::Font font;
    std::cout << "Created the Window." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Loaded Text and Font classes" << std::endl;

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        std::cout << "Created window Function loop" << std::endl;

        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        if (!font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf"))
        {
            std::cout << "Program Halted." << std::endl;
            std::exit(-1);
        }

        std::cout << "Loaded Fonts." << std::endl;
        text.setFont(font);
        text.setString("I am a Test");
        text.setCharacterSize(20);

        window.clear();
        window.draw(text);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be better to move the code that loads the fonts and initializes the `sf::Text` object out of the main processing loop. That is supposed to execute many times a second.

Comment: @Henry Rather than adding `(Solved)` to your title, accept the answer you like the most. That's how we do it here.

Comment: I've heard of that, but  because the Answers I have are basically the same, I can't say one is better than the other. So I'd rather tell people it's 'solved', instead of getting alot more answers, either making it much more complicated, or being a repeated answer.

Comment: @HenrySouthall As the answers were essentially the same I have withdrawn mine to make your choice easier :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing this:

```
font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf")
```

in a loop without a delay. The font should be loaded once at the start of the program, or the OS and your antivirus software will not like what your program is doing (repeatedly accessing the same file on the disk for too long).

As to the delay, you should have:

```
window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);
```

to sync with 60FPS (probably), because you're maxing out CPU thread/GPU, too.

The resulting code, with some non-descriptive output messages removed:

```
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800,600),"Text Test");
    window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);
    std::cout << "Created the Window." << std::endl;

    sf::Text text;
    sf::Font font;

    if (!font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf"))
    {
        std::cout << "Program Halted." << std::endl;
        std::exit(-1);
    }

    std::cout << "Loaded Fonts." << std::endl;
    text.setFont(font);
    text.setString("I am a Test");
    text.setCharacterSize(20);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(text);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's all working fine now. I did purposely put the non-descriptive ones in, because I was genuinely confused about why it wasn't working, so I decided to 'label' most of the functions to spot the error out.

Comment: Ok, it was just weird to me to check if `text` and `font` has been constructed. There's nothing to fail there.